# Installing binutils-2.22 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, compiling

I am trying to install binutils-2.22 on Ubuntu 10.04. I have downloaded the source code of binutils-2.22, configured it with a custom prefix (to not conflict with the system binutils) and built it.

However, I am having trouble linking programs with the new binutils. A program that linked just fine with the system binutils, now gives the following errors at link time:

```
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libXext.so.6, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libgtk-x11-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libXrender.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libgtk-x11-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libXinerama.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libgtk-x11-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libXi.so.6, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libgtk-x11-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libXrandr.so.2, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libgtk-x11-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libXcursor.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libgtk-x11-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libXcomposite.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libgtk-x11-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libXdamage.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libgtk-x11-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libXfixes.so.3, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libgtk-x11-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libpcre.so.3, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libgio-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libresolv.so.2, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libgio-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libselinux.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libgio-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libpixman-1.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libcairo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libdirectfb-1.2.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libcairo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libfusion-1.2.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libcairo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libdirect-1.2.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libcairo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libxcb-render-util.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libcairo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libxcb-render.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libcairo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libxcb.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libcairo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libICE.so.6, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libSM.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/<myname>/Programs/binutils/binutils-2.22/bin/ld: warning: libuuid.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/../lib32/libSM.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

followed by a slew of "undefined reference" errors.

Do I need to do some additional configuration to get binutils-2.22 to work?